# How to embed a single Weibo post

Tags: iframe, embed, weibo

Is it possible to embed a single Weibo post like you can a Twitter post or Instagram photo?

I found this hack for embedding a weibo profile as an iframe:

```
<iframe id="weibo" src="http://widget.weibo.com/weiboshow/index.php?language=&amp;width=0&amp;height=550&amp;fansRow=2&amp;ptype=1&amp;speed=0&amp;skin=1&amp;isTitle=1&amp;noborder=1&amp;isWeibo=1&amp;isFans=1&amp;uid=XXXXXXX&amp;verifier=c73b5007&amp;dpc=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="550"></iframe>
```

But what I am looking for is a single post, not a profile. What I have read is that Weibo's API is very similar to Twitter's so I am hopeful...

Comment: I'm trying to find how to do this myself. I don't have an answer yet, but for others reference [this](http://www.blogs.jbs.cam.ac.uk/digitalstrategy/2014/07/12/embedding-sina-weibo/) is the hack you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, wanting to embed a video from weibo, so if anyone looks for that, here is how:

```
<iframe id="weibo" src="//f.us.sinaimg.cn/0046P1QHlx07kct6BNCo01040200Z1uT.mp4?label=mp4_720p&template=1280x720.28&Expires=1525430838&ssig=k3hdjl4IpV&KID=unistore,video" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="550"></iframe>
```

I hope this helps someone:)

**LATER EDIT:**
It appears that it works only once, then you get a 403 error on the page.